# Did two unquestionably democratic states ever engage in war?

Tags: war, democracy

I was just reading A.fm.'s comment on [this question](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23738/is-enfranchisement-the-answer-to-the-middle-east-problem-or-is-dictatorship-nec).

> [...] and history shows democratic states don't fight one another.

At first I thought this statement was wrong, but thinking further I couldn't find any example of two unquestionably democratic states engagint a war with eachother. I can only find examples of democracy declaring war to a dictatorship (USA invading Irak in 2003) or a dictatorship invading a democracy (for example Germany invading Czechoslovakia in 1938). Cases of two dictatorship attacking eachother are unfortunately too common so that no example is needed...

The best counter-example to A.fm.'s claim I can find is Austria-Hungary declaring war to Serbia in 1914... but both of those countries were more hybrid regimes than full democraties it seems.

France declaring war to Prussia in 1870 is also borderline making it, but both countries were kind of hybrid/half-democraties at this point of time.

Comment: The problem I think you are going to have here is that any conflict not entirely involving modern Western European or North American countries is liable to devolve into a No True Scottsman argument. For example, I could say "War of 1812", but someone could say, "Doesn't count, most of the USA didn't have the vote, and a large portion of it was enslaved."

Comment: Wikipedia has a list for this because Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_between_democracies . Of course, how "democratic" some of these countries were is up for debate.

Comment: @DPenner1 - Hmmm...of those I'd say the "Best Scottman" is probably the Boer Wars. That may just be down to my ignorance on how those states were run, though.

Comment: You are looking at [_**Democratic Peace Theory**_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_peace_theory). I would not consider this history, but **political theory and international relations**. It has been around for a while ... in that sense it is history? And [_this_](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11751/how-accurate-is-russell-on-liberalism-versus-fanaticism-in-war?rq=1)

Comment: Maybe the [Chilean Coup in 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973_Chilean_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat)?  Likewise [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_Guatemalan_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_Iranian_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat). But maybe it is tough to call the US a democracy.

Comment: "The best counter-example to A.fm.'s claim I can find is Austria-Hungary declaring war to Serbia in 1914" Err... Austria-Hungary was one of the most reactionary regimes at the time. It was only a few notches below Russia in how reactionary it was. If anything the surprise of WW1 was how Russia, the mother of all reactionary nations then if anything, ended up allied with two of the most progressive.

Comment: There are no unquestioned democracies, so there can't be any war between them :-)

Comment: The answer strongly depends on your definition of "unquestionably democratic". Whatever example is given one can question whether one of the side was truly democratic.

Comment: @Bregalad note that in 1938, the Germany did not invade Czechoslovakia - you probably mean 1939 (and even that was not a war). In 1938, it was just a peaceful territory transfer (imposed also by several democratic countries, no less).

Comment: Humm... US Civil War between USA and CSA?  Irish War of Independence?

Comment: What is an unquestionable democracy? If they exist, they must be pretty rare and exist only in recent decades.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Indo-Pakistan War of 1971 was fought between Pakistan and India. Both were run by democratic governments at the time. Obviously there was also the matter of the secession of East Pakistan (now Bangladesh) so it was at least half a civil war, but still two democratic powers fought.

Another conflict, on a smaller scale, between India and Pakistan (the Kargil War) occurred in 1999. Again both sides had democratic governments. Here you could argue that Nawaz Sharif did not know about the military action - i.e. it was a military adventure - at least that is what he says about it. But I think that must count.

Although Pakistan has had periods of military rule, I don't think anyone could seriously question Pakistan's democratic nature in 1999.

Comment: Given that the war's ultimate cause was the refusal of those in West Pakistan to allow a government democratically elected by a majority of people - because that majority was in East Pakistan, I don't see how Pakistan can be described as a democracy at that time.

Comment: I agree that the first of the wars was a marginal case. I was assuming that since East Pakistan had declared independence before the war began with India (a short time, but it was a short war) then we could discount the fact that East Pakistanis weren't properly represented - they were now in a different country.

Answer (score 8):

Does the War of 1812 count as two democracies? Enfranchisement was incomplete for both countries, and one even had slavery, but they were still democratic states. Or do those two qualities make them questionable?

Comment: Jinx! Owe me a soda.

Comment: Which war of 1812 ?

Comment: @Bregalad - Probably a reasonable presumption that the one you get by that name from the [English version of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_1812) was the one intended.

Comment: But this was only part of the greater narrative of Napoleonic wars.

Comment: Britain is officially a monarchy, even now. And it certainly was not "unquestionably democratic" in 1812. Neither was US "unquestionably democratic". Women and slaves did not vote.

Comment: Of course, if we hold out for universal enfranchisement, which is even now imperfect, that leaves an awfully narrow historical window, and a very small selection of countries.

Answer (score 1):

What about World War I, and specifically Britain versus Germany? Both were parliamentary democracies with robust opposition parties, a relatively free press, rule of law, independent judiciaries,  but in both cases with a superimposed hereditary monarchy.

Comment: I have a feeling that democracy in Germany (and Austria-Hungary) was limited. Opposition parties were allowed, but they were not much listened to. The military had overwhelming powers that were almost a 2nd government parallel to the civil government. This clearly played a role in the outbreak of WW1 where the monarchy wanted to solve the problem with diplomacy but the generals wanted a war.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast. There is no reason to leave France out, except that France was a republic, while Britain and Germany were (constitutional) monarchies. They are thus a closer parallel.

Comment: @fdb OK, I see the comparison

Comment: Imperial Germany was certainly not a democracy in that foreign and defence policy were not in the remit of the elected parliament. The parliament controlled the budget but not much else.

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin. Where did you read that?

Comment: Have a look here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_(Deutsches_Kaiserreich)

Comment: @fdb see, for instance pp 457 - 459 of the Penguin edition of Alexander Watson's "Ring of Steel" - which describes how Reichstag deputies increasingly sought to use their control over war credits to make the government - which was not accountable to the parliament - listen to them.

Comment: @fdb - that wikipedia article makes clear that the Reichstag didn't control the executive (ie foreign and defence policy) and that it only had powers of co-decision in the budget and on laws.

Comment: The president of France (today) is not accountable to parliament. Would you exclude it from the list of democracies?

Comment: @Bregalad what does listen mean in politics? Parties with parliamentary representation? Military political influence didn't play major role in wwi outbreak, it was clearly fault of politics.

Comment: The President of the Republic in France is elected by the people. It's an inherently democratic decision. The Kaiser was not elected. There was nothing democratic about his appointment of a government. That's a pretty obvious difference and it strikes me that you are being deliberately obtuse in not recognising it.

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin. The Kaiser appointed the German prime minister (Reichskanzler) in the same way that his grandmother (Queen Victoria) appointed the British prime minister. The constitutional framework was the same, even if the political reality was somewhat different.

Comment: That's garbage mate. No British Prime Minister could survive without the confidence of the House of Commons. Look up some basic British constitutional theory because right now you are talking rubbish.